# Reference-based and normal registration with PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I want to implement a solution for a reference-based registration. I want my users to invite their friends via their reference links, but I also want to keep the non-referenced normal registration.

For instance, users are registering to my website via `www.mywebsite.com/user/register`. I also want to make them register via a reference code like `www.mywebsite.com/user/register/1`. I've tried to implement the code below, but my normal registration stopped working after I tried that.

```
if(isset($_GET["ref"])) {
  $ref = intval($_GET["ref"]);
  // register proccesses
}
```

I've tried this rule but my non-referenced part stopped working.

```
RewriteRule ^user/register/(.*)/?$ user/register.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

How can I make both work?

Hope you can help. Thank you.

Comment: How are you routing to register.php *currently*? (Disregarding the reference part you want to add.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having two rules after eachother?

```
RewriteRule ^user/register/(.*)/?$ user/register.php?ref=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/register/?$ user/register.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try in this method.The below is your ref link

```
www.mywebsite.com/user/register?ref=125rhu

if(isset($_GET['ref'])){
 $reffernce_user = /*find the reffered user and put there id here*/
}
else{
 $reffernce_user = 0;
}
```

so if you add this field into your table you can find the user registered through reference and direct registered user.It is a simple method